# Why JFrame.setUndecorated(true) makes the modal dialog behave like a modeless on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, swing, modal-dialog, parent-child

I am investigating the problem of the java swing parent-child window on Linux. When a modal child window is displayed, its behavior is similar to that of a modeless. The parent window can be displayed on front of the child window, and the child window seems to have a parent-child relationship with another window.

I make a demo see below, there is a JFrame parent window named "ParentJFrame" and a no-parent JFrame named "OtherJFrame" which created by "ParentJFrame", when clicking "test" button, "ParentJFrame" will create a child modal dialog named "ChildJDialog", when "ChildJDialog" shows, it seems that this modal JDialog become modeless, clicking anywhere in "ParentJFrame", this parent JFrame show on the top, meanwhile "ChildJDialog" seems become "OtherJFrame"'s children, it always shows on the front of "OtherJFrame", clicking minimize button on "OtherJFrame", they minimized together.

```java
package swing_demo;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame other_frame = new JFrame("OtherJFrame");
        other_frame.setSize(300, 200);
        other_frame.setVisible(true);

        JFrame parent_frame = new JFrame("ParentJFrame");
        parent_frame.setBounds(20, 20, 400, 300);
        parent_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        parent_frame.setUndecorated(true);

        JButton btn = new JButton("test");

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog dia = new JDialog(parent_frame, true);
                dia.setTitle("ChildJDialog");
                dia.setSize(200, 100);
                dia.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        // Setting the frame visibility to true
        parent_frame.add(btn);
        parent_frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When i comment out `parent_frame.setUndecorated(true);`, everything is fine. Does anyone know what the reason is? I need to use `setUndecorated(true);` to make the window have no title bar.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem when I try to run your code. What happens on your platform though when you change the dialog creation line to: `JDialog dia = new JDialog(parent_frame, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);`

Comment: I suspect this is a platform specific issue, seems work okay on MacOS

Comment: Using `JDialog dia = new JDialog(parent_frame, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);` Still the same problem, I used openjdk 11 on debian, also tested on archlinux, the same problem as debian, but tested on Windows, that's good.

Comment: In what desktop environments is this occurring?  Gnome?  KDE?  Something else?

Comment: I am using the MATE desktop environment.

Comment: @VGR You reminded me, I installed Gnome3 and KDE desktop environment on debian, Gnome3 has the same problem but KDE does not.